# Loading Huge single `rdata` vs Loading small multiple `rdata`

Tags: r, performance, save, saving-data, rdata

I have a huge nested list of R objects. I can split them into many smaller lists (say 160) and save them individually in 160 `.rda` or `.rds` files. My question is:

> Is it better (efficient) to load one big `rdata` file into memory and do all the task or load the smaller files when it is needed?

Comment: It depends. There are two resources to consider: CPU and memory. Loading the object on one shot may cause your system to go out of memory, but, if it can handle it, can speed up your code since the object is already there. If you split the object you lose some time in loading and unloading things and this may slow down your process. However, I prefer to use smaller files when needed, since running out of memory can be very bad if it happens.

Comment: Also, You need to be wisely to pick the chunk size (In your case is 160)